# Pointer to managed array in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, c++-cli, managed

Alright, I know how you normally would declare a pointer:

```
void SomeFunction(array<float> ^managedArray)
{
  pin_ptr<float> managedArrayPtr = &managedArray[0];
}
```

This works fine except when managedArray contains no elements. In that case, it throws an IndexOutOfRangeException.

In C# you can do this:

```
void SomeFunction(float[] managedArray)
{
  fixed (float* managedArrayPtr = managedArray)
  {
  }
}
```

Which does no memory access and works even if managedArray is empty.
Do I really have to check for the number of elements everywhere I use pointers to managed arrays or does C++/CLI have a way to do it like C#?
It should be using the 'lea' instruction in ASM which does no memory access.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much point in trying to read from the array when it is empty.  Just check for that:

```
void SomeFunction(array<float> ^managedArray)
{
    if (managedArray->Length > 0) {
        pin_ptr<float> managedArrayPtr = managedArray;
        //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, but it's annoying to check that everywhere. I was hoping for a shorthand since something like this is used very often in pointer languages. Anyways I'll use this.

Comment: *Everywhere*?  You need to use this kind of code sparingly, pinning isn't healthy for the garbage collector.

Comment: I'm wrapping a native library and I do indeed use it everywhere. Sure, it might not really be 'everywhere' generally, but while wrapping this library, yes everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Unfortunately I am not that familiar with C++/CLI. I do know that you can do the pinning manually using the `GCHandle` struct and will work on empty arrays. It is not as elegant as using `pin_ptr` though.

```
void SomeFunction(array<float> ^managedArray) 
{ 
 GCHandle handle = GCHandle::Alloc(managedArray, GCHandleType::Pinned);
 try 
 {
  float* ptr = (float*)(void*)handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
 }
 finally
 {
  handle.Free();
 }
}
```

Comment: But then I might as well just check the length. I was hoping for a quick way, like an operator or something.

Comment: Yeah, checking the length is probably the way to go. I googled quite a bit I could not find an elegant solution either.